# Why was this bounty awarded by the Community user?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties, community-user

I accepted an answer to this question:

[How to develop a web application compatible with multiple database management systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581969/how-to-develop-a-web-application-compatible-with-multiple-database-management-sys)

but the bounty was awarded by Community ♦ to another answer. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The awarding of bounties has been disassociated from the accepting of answers. So you can accept one answer and award the bounty to another. It also means that other users can offer a bounty on *your* question.

Read Jeff's blog post on [Improvements to the Bounty System](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)

The auto awarding rules for bounties (half the bounty going to the highest voted answer supplied since the bounty was set) hasn't changed.

It does mean that you need to remember to award the bounty, otherwise it will be auto awarded and it might not go to the same answer as you accepted - as in this case.

Comment: Hi Chris, As per your comment i do understand the bounty may be automatically awarded to high rated answer. In my case in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923227/cordova-phonegap-using-external-web-page-in-app-while-maintaining-header-footer/ , the bounty was awarded to non related answer which was fakely rated.In fact the user account who was awarded the bounty is suspended and the questioner has accepted my answer. I have 2 question on this. 1)Can the awarded bounty be revoked 2)Can the questioner or community transfer it to accepted right answer?

Comment: @Gandhi - 1) no (other than by deleting the recipient), 2) no.

Comment: Even the moderator is not authorized for the same? This looks more of a flaw that an unrelated answer wins bounty and the accepted answer goes unrewarded right?

Comment: @Gandhi - moderators have no special powers here. We can't change the recipient of a bounty. I'm not sure employees can either - even with database access, because I'm sure it wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris. But how to request or bring it to someone's notice to fix this flaw? Could you give me some lead on this?

Comment: @Gandhi - you could create a [meta-tag:feature-request] - but do a search first to see if it's been suggested already.

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris. But i dont see any link to request new feature. Do i need to ask it as a question?

Comment: @Gandhi - yes. You ask a question with the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag.