# Bounty bug? Only awarded half when the answer had been accepted

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why didn't I get the bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty)
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I accepted this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/153291/cant-mount-o-loop-an-iso-from-an-nfs-share-rhel/186890#186890) for this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/153291/cant-mount-o-loop-an-iso-from-an-nfs-share-rhel/) before the bounty period ended.

Why was only half of it awarded to the answerer?

Comment: I don't really want to mark this as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63873/why-was-this-bounty-awarded-by-community), only because there are at least 3 reports from even earlier about this. So give me a moment~ ♪

Comment: I'll settle for [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55199/why-didnt-i-get-the-bounty). It's about not getting the bounty at all, but the reason is exactly the same, and is what Popular points out below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounty rules have changed; awarding bounties is now a separate action from accepting answers.

The details are available in [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).