# Bounty auto-awarded, even though I had accepted an answer. Why?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounty bug? Only awarded half when the answer had been accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64864/bounty-bug-only-awarded-half-when-the-answer-had-been-accepted)

I recently asked a [question with an attached bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899322). My question was answered, and I accepted the most correct and timely answer. When I visited the site today, I was surprised to find a message saying the bounty had been auto-awarded, and that the recipient only got half the bounty (I was expecting him to get it all).

1. What did I do wrong? (I'm assuming it was an oversight on my part that meant my accepted answer didn't also get the bounty.)
2. Is there any way to retroactively give the recipient the other half of the bounty he earned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bounty bug? Only awarded half when the answer had been accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64864/bounty-bug-only-awarded-half-when-the-answer-had-been-accepted) Which is probably a dupe of a dupe of a dupe of a dupe but hey :)

Comment: I accept that the first part is indeed a duplicate. The second part (Is there any way to give the recipient the remainder of the bounty that they earned?) Appears to have remained unanswered.