# Why didn't the Community User automatically award 50% of bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, beta-phase

If someone starts a bounty and doesn't manually award it, the [Community User should award 50% to the highest-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63873/160519).

However, that [did not happen](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4048/koray-tugay?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on *[this NetworkEngineering.SE question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6014/775)*.

Interestingly enough, the same user started a bounty at roughly the same time on [this Electronics.SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/97775/4179), and Community User correctly awarded half the bounty.

Unless I'm mistaken, this is a bug... since we have a solid comparison from the same user on two different sites, on the surface I assume it's related to being in beta...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Neither answer qualified; both had been posted *before* the bounty was started.

The [post history](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/6014/revisions) shows the bounty was started on Jan 29 at 15:04, but the two answers were posted on Jan 25 at 13:14 and Jan 27 at 13:42.

The [detailed bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) states:

> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given **after the bounty was started**

Emphasis mine.

This is entirely [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and the behaviour doesn't differ between beta and graduated sites.